# How to add two baseadapters to listview in android?

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

How to add two base adapters to listView in android? I need two adapters, one is for showing phonebook contact and another is for showing application registered contact, i was trying to use Merge adapter, but its not working properly, can anyone help me to solve this issue.

Comment: use android.database.
MergeCursor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hmm, this should be easy.

1) You can create one adapter with updateData method inside, and then just call it from your activity and then adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();.

For example:
Put this in your adapter:

```
public void updateData(ArrayList<Object> newData)
{
 this.data = newData;
}
```

Then, in your activity you call this:

```
  myAdapter.updateData(data);
  myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

2) Create two adapters with different data.

To set the adapter just call:

```
listView.setAdapter(adapter1);
```

And second one:

```
listView.setAdapter(adapter2);
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response but your solutions no longer useful for me, i tried both but my application is force closing. if you know any other way then help me with example for more understanding

Comment: Post your code, i cannot help you with no code..also add your logcat output so i can see crash

Comment: Hi, Finally i achieved the task by merging two array-list into one array-list and set that array-list to listview. Thanks for valuable responses.